# SwiftUI DidBecomeActiveNotification - all values are lost

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am new to iOS, and I am developing my fairy tales application with SwiftUI. Everything is ok, but I found one error - when entering background and returning back to the app, all data gets lost from my View.

I tried to debug the app, and I see that when receiving willEnterForegroundNotification, the data still exists. But, when receiving didBecomeActiveNotification, data already gets lost.

Could anyone help me to understand, how to preserve data in the View, when entering back foreground?

```
import SwiftUI
import DynamicColor

struct FairyTaleStoryView: View, FairyModelDelegate, WebImageLoadProtocol {
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
    @State private var offset = CGSize.zero // for gesture recognition - how far the user has dragged
    let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
    let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
    let storyId : Int
    @State var pos : Int = 0
    @ObservedObject var networkManager = NetworkManager()
    var musicManager = MusicManager()
    var states = FairyStates()
    @State var textShowing = 1
    
   .....
    
   var storyPresenter : some View {
      ....
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            storyPresenter
                .navigationBarTitle("")
                .navigationBarHidden(true)
                .onAppear(perform: {
                    self.networkManager.delegate = self
                    self.networkManager.fetchFairyTale(id: storyId)
                })
            
        }
        .background(Color(hexString: Colors.BackgroundColor))
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        .onDisappear() {
            stopSound()
            stopMusic()
        }
        .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification)) { _ in
            print(networkManager.fairyTale) // prints an object
            }
        .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification)) { _ in
            print(networkManager.fairyTale) // prints empty object
            }
    }
    

}

struct FairyTaleStoryView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        FairyTaleStoryView(storyId: 0)
    }
}
```

Comment: It seams that I've found a workaround to this error. The problem is with ObservedObject networkManager. When entering back the foreground, it gets lost. So I changed my code to use local state variable fairyTale (the copy of networkManager.fairyTale), instead of using networkManager.fairyTale in the View. Then everything works fine! But still, maybe you can say, what is wrong with my ObservedObject networkManager, why does it get lost when entering back foreground?

Comment: Model objects should typically have a lifetime that is the same as your app, while views are ephemeral and disposable. Your view creates a new `NetworkManager` instance when it is created. A better approach is for the `NetworkManager` instance to come from the environment

Comment: Thank you very much, I am reading now about EnvironmentObject, this is something new for me, but I definitely should implement it...